# How to define a convex surface in case of refraction?

Tags: optics, refraction, conventions

In an exam at high school level,  it was said, "ray goes from optically denser to rarer medium through a convex surface. It forms a real image...." this was a part of the question. Now I thought that a [convex surface](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=convex+surface) can be defined as the surface that bulges out towards the incident ray. But my teacher made the opposite diagram, what is the convention in play here? How would you define a convex surface?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you are standing.  A convex surface is one that bulges out towards the person who is talking about it.

Since we do not live inside glass, everyone knows what a bi-convex glass lens is - one that bulges out on both sides as seen by someone who lives in air.  Note that while it bulges out towards the incident ray arriving from the air, the second surface would be concave as seen by the ray inside the glass.  Nevertheless this is a bi-convex lens!

The exam was worded poorly, if your quotation is correct,

> ray goes from optically denser to rarer medium through a convex surface.

This is simply meaningless.  We could place ourselves in the standpoint of the incoming ray, but why would we? - we don't live in an optically dense medium.

This is why diagrams are a good idea!!!!

Comment: akrasia: "_A convex surface is one that bulges out towards the person who is talking about it._" -- You've got a (virtual! ;) point there: a **cave** is usually understood from the perspective of "being (wrapped) inside"; hence it's said to have a "concave surface". Then as the opposite (watching a cave from the outside): a "_convex surface_". But: Does a surface whose cross section is shaped like the capital letter "B" "_bulge out towards_" a person (looking at it from the right-hand side), for instance? "_we do not live inside glass_" -- But, typically: air. Some, part-time, even: water.

Comment: The exam was indeed very vague. My point is, can we fix our observation point as the source of light? And then see of the light hits a bulge or a cave?

Comment: Saurabh Raje: "_can we fix our observation point as the source of light?_" -- Regarding optical imaging there's surely a practical, conventional "optician's view": "along the ray(s)", from object to image. In the case of your example, that's just the reverse of the (practical, conventional) "lensmaker's view": from the outside of the (dense) material. My point: The corresponding surface has a particular **intrinsic geometry**. Now: it may be said (concisely) that the surface to be considered in your exam must have been "bulging away from the material". But **how exactly** should we draw that??

Answer (score 0):

> How would you define a convex surface?

I'd call a set $\mathcal S$ (of five or more elements) "convex" if for each element $A \in \mathcal S$ any two [circumspheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_sphere) of $A$ and any triples of distinct elements of $\mathcal S$ other than $A$ have the property that the center of the smaller circumsphere is inside the larger circumsphere;
in other words: that the distance between the centers of two such circumspheres involving $A$ **is less than** the distance between $A$ and the center of the larger circumsphere.

Basically, this distinguishes a set which is "(everywhere) convex" from one which would be called "wrinkled". (And I'm not so much concerned with possible additional conditions permitting to speak of such a "convex" set as "*surface*" at all.)

But your question raises an additional problem:

> "ray goes from optically denser to rarer medium through a convex surface. It forms a real image...."

So there's a definition needed for deciding "on which side of the surface" there's "*optically denser medium*". This concerns not just strictly "*the surface*", but "the interior (of the lense)".

Now, for any five elements ("points") of a [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) it is (generally) possible to decide whether one of them is "in the interior" of the remaining four, or not. (The meaning should be obvious; the exact definition in terms of distance ratios between the points under consideration is a little cumbersome, but I'll write it down if someone likes to know.)

Based on that, for any four elements $A$, $B$, $J$ and $K$ of a given "convex" set $\mathcal S$ (in the sense defined above) and one additional "point with *denser medium* $M$" (which obviously shoud not belong to set $\mathcal S$) it can be determined

- whether $M$ is in the interior of $A$, $B$, $J$ and $K$,
- or $A$ is in the interior of $B$, $J$, $K$ and $M$,
- or $B$ is in the interior of $A$, $J$, $K$ and $M$, etc.
- or neither.

If, in this sense, **there is** "*denser medium* inside the lens surface", while there had been **no** "surface inside the *denser medium*" in the above sense (or in other words: there had been **no** "*denser medium* on the outside of the lens surface"), then, indeed, suitable light rays can form a real image.

A corresponding illustration would be (either the left or right face of) a biconvex lense:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_%28optics%29#mediaviewer/File:Lens1.svg

**Edit**
Note that what above I defined and called (off the seat of my pants)

- *a set which is "(everywhere) convex"*

would be called in more standard terms

- *a subset of the [boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29) of a [convex set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set)*.

Comment: talk about using a sledgehammer!

Comment: @akrasia: "_talk about using a sledgehammer!_" -- Talk about giving a forthright, self-respecting, defensible answer.